# How to import 3rd party framework privately for your Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, carthage, swift-package-manager

If I'm building a framework A and import **Reachability**, maybe via Carthage of Swift PM, although the app using framework A would never be able to use `A.Reachability`, `import Reachability` still appears in interface of final built of `A`.
How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't support internal/private imports at the moment. All of your imports are forwarded to anyone using your framework. If you look at Foundation for example it pulls in a lot of other frameworks such as GCD and Darwin.

If you need to hide it then you are currently limited to copying the code into your framework and making sure it is all internal/private so people importing your framework don't see it.